# Filter by BTS.ReceiveLocationName in orchestration receive shape

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I tried to filter by BTS.ReceiveLocationName in orchestration receive shape but I can not see it in a filters:

[image]

Do someone know what can be a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because there is no such property

You could try BTS.InboundTransportLocation and give it the URI of the Receive Location

[image: BTS.InboundTransportLocation Property]

It is one of the few automatically promoted properties of an received message.

[image: Promoted Properties]

Another option is to have a Pipeline Component in the Receive Location that sets a promoted property that you then filter on. We usually do this via a [BRE Pipeline Component](https://github.com/mbrimble/brepipelineframework) and a Business Rule to set the Property.  This avoids having the change the filter per environment due to the URI being different.

Comment: Thank you! Works for me. Of course then i need to change URLs before deployment to QA or Prod, but solution works for me, thanks again!